# Onclick window.location with parameter passed

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, append, src

I am currently trying to retrieve records from the database and append each of them so that they can be displayed.

I figured out that there is a syntax error somewhere in this particular line, the part where the image is appended. I am clueless about how to append correctly the image as a link which can be clicked on to go the next page with the parameter arr[i]itemID passed.

```
$("#wallcontentset").append("<b>" + arr[i].categoryName + "</b><br/>" + arr[i].itemName + "<br/>" + arr[i].price + "<br/>" + arr[i].soldStatus + "<br/>" + "<a href='#' onclick="window.location='viewtheitem.html?itemID=" + arr[i].itemID + "'"> + <img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile + "'height='150'></a><br/><hr>");
```

Can somebody help me out?

I changed it to the code displayed below but nothing happens when the image appended and displayed is clicked on:

```
enter code here $("#wallcontentset").append("<b>" + arr[i].categoryName + "</b><br/>" + arr[i].itemName + "<br/>" + arr[i].price + "<br/>" + arr[i].soldStatus + "<br/>" + "<a href='#' onclick=\"window.location='viewtheitem.html?itemID=" + arr[i].itemID + "\"><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile + "'height='150'></a><br/><hr>");
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a link?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the end of your code you will see you have a quotation mark problem

```
+ "<a href='#' onclick="window.location='viewtheitem.html?itemID=" + arr[i].itemID + "'"> + <img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile + "'height='150'></a><br/><hr>");
```

You start a new string with " but use the same sign in your onclick so you end your string. So you either have to use ' instead of " or escape your quotation mark.
So one way to do this would be:

```
+ "<a href='#' onclick=\"window.location='viewtheitem.html?itemID=" + arr[i].itemID + "\"> + <img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile + "'height='150'></a><br/><hr>");
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Joe, I had changed the codes but nothing happens when the image appended and displayed is clicked on. It seems that there is still a syntax error with the link. I had updated my question.

Comment: Please break your code into multiple lines and check the browser console and see which line produces an error.